# Unable to fetch document libraries of sites in Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am unable to fetch the default document libraries in sites from last day. Till last day every thing was working fine.Have been there any changes in the GRAPH API /sites/{site-id}/drives. It will be really helpful if someone help me in this.

Thanks & Regards,

Sayali A. Rathi

Comment: Are you getting `{ "error": { "code": "unauthenticated", "message": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.", "innerError": { "request-id": "7a0f1a4a-eb8e-427b-8e76-cb44ce4ae661", "date": "2017-11-24T13:59:40" } } }`

Comment: Can you try it again? I think this may be related to [issue 215](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/215) which has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. `/drives` endpoint used to work today in the morning, and now I'm getting "Access denied" error.
I'm getting the error on multiple tenants, so looks like it's global Graph API issue.
Meanwhile `/drive` endpoint works fine and returns default library of the site correctly.

UPDATE: I can confirm that the issue is now resolved by Microsoft: [issue 215](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/215)